# Zephir Error : Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/utils.so'

Tags: zephir

Today, i installed 'Zephir' on my ubuntu machine. After spending some hour(going through zephir docs) with Zephir I noticed 2 things. 
- The 'config.json' file which suppose to be created inside of "utlis" folder(as of zephir doc) it's getting created outside of "utlis" folder. 
-  After successfully testing 1st example 'Greeting'(as of zephir doc ) when i created the 2nd example of "Filter" Class & tried to build the extension by "zephir build" command i got following error..

```
Error message : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/utils.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/utils.so: undefined symbol: zephir_Utils_Bark_init in Unknown on line 0
```

In fact, i feel whenever i tried to create a new Class inside "utlis" folder i got that error. I made some quick google search about the error but didn't get any result.

Guys any idea, what's going wrong... ?

Comment: Try:
zephir fullclean
zephir build

Comment: I tried that but getting this error..

opsol@system-6:~/Documents/Practice/Zephir/utils$ zephir full-clean
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/utils.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/utils.so: undefined symbol: zephir_Utils_Filter_init in Unknown on line 0
Exception: Unrecognized action "full-clean"

Comment: have the same problem, I'm using ubuntu 13.10 x86 with the newest zephir version

Comment: @sinaneker : Hey, check out this discussion. I hope this will solve your problem.

Link : http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1503/zephir-error-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php5-2012121